# Gae/cloudsql error: Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am running GAE/python application (App Engine Standard Edition) in same project as (2nd Gen) CloudSQL, in same Region as well.

However I continue to get following error

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~xx.xxx.xx.xx' (using password: NO)")
```

The apps automatically get authorized, so can't figure out the issue. Also shouldn't the connection be from root@localhost instead of cloudsqlproxy? Do I need to create a 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy user?

Comment: *My Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117314/er-access-denied-error-cloudsql

Answer (score 3):

If you set a root password for your instance, you will need to specify that password when connecting.

First Generation instances come out of the box with a root user with an empty password, but Second Generation instances do not. For a Second Generation instance, you should set the root password and use that in your app.

This could be clarified in our documentation. Not creating a root user with an empty password avoids the issue of opening the database wide open in case the network ACLs are misconfigured.

Comment: Great. Thanks, It works if I add passwd parameter. This is strange, since I understood from documents that GAE can automatically access without password.

Comment: Can you point me to any docs that might be confusing so we can improve them? The connections go through normal mysql authentication. You can either use the default root account or create a different one but in either case you must specify the correct credentials for the user.

Comment: @Vadim, I believe that Nick was confused because on Cloud SQL first generation the password was not required when connecting through GAE. IMO it's worth mentioning explicitly in the docs.

Comment: That's a good point Tzach. It looks like we already have an internal issue filed to clarify this in our documentation. I'll go ahead and add this to my answer.

Comment: @Vadim, I had the same issue.  Here is a manual, which contains no information about password https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/

Comment: @Vadim One year later, the documentation for this is still confusing. One of the main confusions is that the documentation tells the user to put secrets (i.e. the Cloud SQL user password) in `app.yaml`, but that sounds like a very bad idea as that file is usually in version control.

Comment: I notice that gcloud lets me create second gen instances without a root password, and they work for a while, but eventually I get locked out with this error.  I suspect that there some kind of window where the user is allowed to set their own password via mysql, and if they don't, one gets set for them.  If I'm right about this, then I wish google would've just forced me to specify a password via gcloud in the first place so that I wouldn't be locked out of my data now.