# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR CloudSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am receiving an error which looks like this (in my functions log)

Access denied for user `\'varun_admin\'@\'cloudsqlproxy~84.117.112.32\' (using password: YES)',`

```
    sqlMessage:
`\'varun_admin\'@\'cloudsqlproxy~84.117.112.32\' (using password: YES)',`
    sqlState: '28000',
```

fatal: true }
(`84.117.112.32`) intentionally modified.

I have double checked my `username` and `password`, In fact, I made a request from workbench and it went fine.

This is how I am creating/initialising my sql

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const config = require('./../../config.js')


const connectionName = config.DB_CONNECTION_NAME
console.log(`Connection name: ${config.DB_CONNECTION_NAME}`)
const configSQL = {
    host: config.DB_HOST,
    user: config.DB_USER,
    password: config.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: config.DB_DATABASE
}

// Connection to cloud sql in production

if (!process.env.dev) {
    configSQL.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
}

//SQL Config
const pool = mysql.createPool(configSQL)

// Checking if it was connected sucessfully or not on server startup
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err)
        return
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId)
    connection.release()
    return
})
```

And the following function would typically make a call to get data

```
const getEverythingFromTable = tableName => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
            if (error) return reject(error)
            const query = `SELECT * FROM ${tableName}`
            connection.query(query, (err, response) => {
                connection.destroy()
                if (err) return reject(err)
                return resolve(response)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

SQL Logs

[image]

**Update: 1**

These are the environment values I am passing to the Cloud SQL Config

[image]

(Please refer to the code snippet above)

Where my cloudSQL config in the UI looks like this

[image]
[image]
[image]

How I am invoking functions/ calling them, the NodeJS code for it is above.

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting can be caused by an issue with your password or with the SSL encryption that is being used, as mentioned in the [Verify how you connect](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#how-connect) section of the documentation.

I actually tried to see if I could reproduce the issue by I changing my instance configurations to **Allow only SSL connections**, as suggested by the [Enforcing SSL/TLS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance#enforcing-ssl) section of the documentation. However, it didn’t cause the issue for me

This would not usually be a problem since, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56665920/11765092), the connections from Cloud Functions are encrypted by default when you use the **cloudsqlproxy**, but I had to test it in case something changed.

I also tried changing the configuration in order to restrict the access to my instance even more. However the only thing that failed my connection was disabling the connection through the Public IP and only allowing it through the Private one, and this made so the connection did not even reach the instance.

Since you mentioned you are able to connect with the Workbench, I believe there are 2 possible causes for your issue:

1. There could be a problem with the encoding of some characters in your
   password, that only get mess up when trying to access it from the
   **env** variables. I suggest you try with a very basic password to see
   if you get the same result.
2. There could be an issue with the encryption of the connection from
   the Cloud Function. If that is the case, this would be very specific
   to your project and the best way to address this issue would be to
   open an issue on [Google’s Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com), or to open a support
   case, in case you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/#support-plans).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have been trying and failing to connect mysql and my google cloud function for 2 days. I followed everything in the Google documentation. I also created the mysql user via GCP with auto-generating the password.  And I was getting the error "Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'redacted'@'cloudsqlproxy~x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)

Changing the password to a basic password as @pessolato suggested fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Cloud SQL user `varun_admin` has the permission to connect from host `cloudsqlproxy~84.117.112.32`. This could also be `%`, but I'd rather recommend to permit only what is required to connect (which is a single host only). Also make sure to flush privileges on mySQL, so that the account changes will be applied instantly. Also see [Configuring SSL/TLS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance).

Comment: I am able to connect, add query, basically perform everything from workbench. Also, this the privileges user have `% (any host) ` and I did restart my sql

Comment: @anny123 workbench might use SSL tunnel (remotely connecting from `localhost`); and `admin@%` is a risky configuration. see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#mysqllogs

Comment: Martin can you simplify your comment? I am not concerned about the security yet (just want to make it work first). 

The logs, log the same error. `Access denied for user 'varun_admin'@'...`

Comment: Also, For workbench I added my iPv4 in cloud SQl connections, for Firebase functions (on production), I have added anything. Do I need to whitelist/add anything?

Comment: Just see the mySQL server logs, which might tell why exactly (this question only features the SQL state, but not the actual error code). that `configSQL` has no `ssl` configuration either, which should possibly be set up.